# Can anybody help to resolve the TypeError: 'float' object is not callable' in following code

Tags: python

I am writing a function for velocity and acceleration in the code below:

```
from math import exp

def kinematics(x,t,dt=1E-4):

    x=x(t)
    v_x=(x(t+dt)-x(t-dt))/(2*dt)
    a_x=(x(t+dt)-2*x(t)+x(t-dt))/(dt**2)
    return x,v_x,a_x

x=lambda t:exp(-(t-4)**2)

print(kinematics(x,5,dt=1E-5))
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Can anybody kindly point out the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

You're reassigning your lambda to the return value of the lambda.

```
x=x(t)
```

After this point, `x` is no longer a `lambda`, it's a `float`.

Comment: Thank you very much! In order to return x in function I have to write it at the end of other statements!!

Answer (score 2):

You are redining `x` in the first line of the function:

```
def kinematics(x,t,dt=1E-4):
    x=x(t)
    ...
```

Use this:

```
def kinematics(x,t,dt=1E-4):
    v_x=(x(t+dt)-x(t-dt))/(2*dt)
    a_x=(x(t+dt)-2*x(t)+x(t-dt))/(dt**2)
    return x(t),v_x,a_x
```